# DIV with 100% height within Iframe causes scrollbar to be cut off

Tags: css, html, scrollbar

I'm having problems with a div within an iFrame, and I've looked at about a dozen posts on this site to no avail. Basically, the content of the iframe has a scrollbar and the Iframe cuts it off.

As recommended by posts on this site I have set the height of html and body to some absolute value (170px) because the children use height:100%, but this does not work. I've also tried setting the height of the children to 170px, and this did not work either. The only thing that seems to work is setting the iframe to some number > 230 px. However, I'd prefer the iframe height to remain at 170px.

**In general, I'm looking for a way to have a two viewports, one title section that does not scroll and one content section that scrolls within an iframe. The content should be displayed with 1 vertical scrollbar to scroll the content section.**

My code is included below, with theiframe I am using.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <iframe src="/html/scrolling2.html" scrolling="no" style="height:170px"/>
</body>
</html>


<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
html, body {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  border:0;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  height:inherit;
  min-height:inherit;
}

.parent_div {
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    border:0px
}

.wrapper_div {
  margin: 0;
  padding:0px 0px 0px 3px;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  min-height:100%;
}

.wrapper #title_table .titleHeader_row th.coltitle_cell {
  border: 1px solid #a7cbe3;
  border-left: none;
  font: bold 11px;
  min-height: 35px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.record_div {
  margin:0px;
  width:100%;
  height:100%; /*need this to take up remaining height not occupied by title_table*/
  overflow:auto;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="parent_div" id="listing">
  <DIV class="wrapper_div" >
    <TABLE id="title_table" >
      <TR >
        <TH class="coltitle_cell">123
        </TH>
        <TH class="coltitle_cell">123<br/>123
        </TH>
        <TH class="coltitle_cell">123<br/>123<br/>123
        </TH>
        <TH class="coltitle_cell">123<br/>123<br/>123
        </TH>
        <TH class="coltitle_cell">123<br/>123
        </TH>
        <TH class="coltitle_cell">123<br/>123
        </TH>
        <TH class="coltitle_cell">123<br/>123
        </TH>
        <TH class="coltitle_cell">123<br/>123
        </TH>
                <TH class="coltitle_cell">123<br/>123
        </TH>
        </TR>
        </TABLE>
  <DIV class="record_div"  id="coldata_div" >
    <TABLE class="record_table" id="coldata_table">
      <TR>
        <TD class="dummy_cell"></TD>
        <TH >123
        </TH>
        <TH >123<br/>123
        </TH>
        <TH >123<br/>123<br/>123
        </TH>
        <TH >123<br/>123<br/>123
        </TH>
        <TH >123<br/>123
        </TH>
        <TH >123<br/>123
        </TH>
        <TH >123<br/>123
        </TH>
        <TH >123<br/>123
        </TH>
        </TR>
              <TR>
        <TD ></TD>
        <TH >123
        </TH>
        <TH >123<br/>123
        </TH>
        <TH >123<br/>123<br/>123
        </TH>
        <TH >123<br/>123<br/>123
        </TH>
        <TH >123<br/>123
        </TH>
        <TH >123<br/>123
        </TH>
        <TH >123<br/>123
        </TH>
        <TH >123<br/>123
        </TH>
        </TR>
                      <TR>
        <TD ></TD>
        <TH >123
        </TH>
        <TH >123<br/>123
        </TH>
        <TH >123<br/>123<br/>123
        </TH>
        <TH >123<br/>123<br/>123
        </TH>
        <TH >123<br/>123
        </TH>
        <TH >123<br/>123
        </TH>
        <TH >123<br/>123
        </TH>
        <TH >123<br/>123
        </TH>
        </TR>
                              <TR>
        <TD ></TD>
        <TH >123
        </TH>
        <TH >123<br/>123
        </TH>
        <TH >123<br/>123<br/>123
        </TH>
        <TH >123<br/>123<br/>123
        </TH>
        <TH >123<br/>123
        </TH>
        <TH >123<br/>123
        </TH>
        <TH >123<br/>123
        </TH>
        <TH >123<br/>123
        </TH>
        </TR>
                              <TR>
        <TD ></TD>
        <TH >123
        </TH>
        <TH >123<br/>123
        </TH>
        <TH >123<br/>123<br/>123
        </TH>
        <TH >123<br/>123<br/>123
        </TH>
        <TH >123<br/>123
        </TH>
        <TH >123<br/>123
        </TH>
        <TH >123<br/>123
        </TH>
        <TH >123<br/>123
        </TH>
        </TR>
        </TABLE>
</div>
</DIV>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you have 2 `html` and `body` part?

Comment: Because I'm using an iframe. So one html is contains solely the iframe. The other html, scrolling2.html, is where I have the relevant html code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I see the problem in what you want to do by your CSS comment:

> ```
>    /*need this to take up remaining height not occupied by title_table*/
> ```

The problem is that browsers don't really understand the concept of *remaining space*. Instead, you have to tell it how much space is available and/or how much to use.

Try wrapping your title table in a div with this style:

```
#title_wrapper {
    height:20%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

And then use this style on your second section to take up the "remaining" space:

```
.record_div {
  height:80%;
  overflow:auto;
}
```